# Scala Play json : functionnal operation error

Tags: scala, playframework, functional-programming, play-json

When I compile the following code :

```
import $ivy.{ `com.typesafe.play::play-json:2.6.8` } // for ammonite users

import play.api.libs.json.{JsPath, Writes}

case class Collect(
    auto_redirect: Boolean,
    collect_shipping_address: Boolean,
    collect_phone_number: Boolean,
    collect_email: Boolean,
    collect_country: Boolean,
  )

import play.api.libs.functional.syntax._
lazy val writes: Writes[Collect]  = (
  (JsPath \ "auto_redirect").write[Boolean] and
  (JsPath \ "collect_shipping_address").write[Boolean] and
  (JsPath \ "collect_phone_number").write[Boolean] and
  (JsPath \ "collect_email").write[Boolean] and
  (JsPath \ "collect_country").write[Boolean]
)(Collect.unapply _)
```

I get the following error :

```
cmd4.sc:5: overloaded method value apply with alternatives:
  [B](f: B => (Boolean, Boolean, Boolean, Boolean, Boolean))(implicit fu: play.api.libs.functional.ContravariantFunctor[play.api.libs.json.OWrites])play.api.libs.json.OWrites[B] <and>
  [B](f: (Boolean, Boolean, Boolean, Boolean, Boolean) => B)(implicit fu: play.api.libs.functional.Functor[play.api.libs.json.OWrites])play.api.libs.json.OWrites[B]
 cannot be applied to (ammonite.$sess.cmd2.Collect => Option[(Boolean, Boolean, Boolean, Boolean, Boolean)])
  (JsPath \ "collect_email").write[Boolean] and
```

Edit: correction after comments.

Comment: you are missing the field names on the `JsPath.write`, check: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ScalaJsonCombinators#writes

Comment: @AlexITC that didn't change anything. Still have the error.

Answer (score 1):

The issue was that I forgot to unlift the function. It is in the documentation : https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ScalaJsonCombinators#writes

```
  lazy val writes: Writes[Collect]  = (
    (JsPath \ "auto_redirect").write[Boolean] and
    (JsPath \ "collect_shipping_address").write[Boolean] and
    (JsPath \ "collect_phone_number").write[Boolean] and
    (JsPath \ "collect_email").write[Boolean] and
    (JsPath \ "collect_country").write[Boolean]
  )(unlift(Collect.unapply))
```

Answer (score 0):

Well you want to convert the `service.coingate.model.Collect` to a `JsonValue` but you forgot to add the names of the `Collect` fields within the `val writes`.

Please look at the [Json writes documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ScalaJsonCombinators#Writes) within Playframework.

Comment: That didn't change anything.

Comment: @Moebius are you getting all the fields? Can you copy/paste the data you are getting, before trying to make it into Json?

Comment: it is not a runtime issue, it is a compile time issue. It doesn't even compile so there's no data involved.

Comment: In your case class why there is a `,` after the `collect_country`? ;-)

Comment: this is exactly the same as coma at all. It is convenient if you want to add a field after the last or move the last field to another place. Then you don't have to add/delete coma.